# Why we use 1/2 in Shannon–Fano–Elias coding

Tags: algorithm, encoding, compression, decoding

Why do we use 1/2 as a coefficient of p(x) in [Shannon–Fano–Elias coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano%E2%80%93Elias_coding).

We could have used 1/3, 1/4, ....

Comment: Have you tried that? Was the resulting coding still a prefix code?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. For the example in [Shannon–Fano–Elias coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano%E2%80%93Elias_coding) I changed the coefficient to 1/3. I obtained this code: 000, 011, 1010, 110. It's still a prefix code.

Comment: Might be better suited to CompSci.SE.